# Most simple way to get authenticated member using Laravel

Tags: php, angular, laravel, authentication

I'm pretty new in Laravel and i also googled a lot about this topic but was not able to find strict answer. I have idea how to get authenticated member on really easy way, but i just wanted to verify with some more experienced developers. 
So first of all i need this in one very simple admin app, that means i do not need any kind of advanced authentication. On API side i use Laravel, and on UI i have angular 6 app.

Edit: I know that Laravel has built in authentication, and logging in works well, but i'm not sure how to re use it and to get authenticated member on page refresh. Just note that i'm using Angular on UI side.

My idea is to use cookie session based authentication, in theory when member logs in, i will set cookie with members id (probably good idea is to hash that value), and on refresh i can check for that cookie (get id, find member by id and return it, that way i have authenticated member).

Anyone knows what is the most basic way to do it, is it possible to use something like this, so when member logs in i can do:

```
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');
```

and on refresh i can do

```
$value = $request->session()->get('key');
```

My questions for this are:

Is this correct approach ?
How to set for example session to last for 20 mins ?
What is good way to put as key and value in order to get authenticated member ?
What is good way to create middleware based on this technique ?

Comment: Laravel has its own core authentication module. Check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Comment: Laravel already comes with an [Authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built in. You should probably have a look at that first.

Comment: I know that, but i'm not sure how to get authenticated member in my angular app, when i try to get Auth::User() i get nothing...

Comment: You cant use Laravel module or variabel inside Angular. You must go for Laravel passport (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport) or JWT token.

Comment: You need to use Laravel passport for authentication, more specifically use password grant authentication.